# Webform CiviCRM Contribution Fails

Tags: civicrm, webforms

I've got a webform set-up to integrate with CiviCRM using the Drupal Webform CiviCRM module.

The pay later option is working, and the checksum populating the fields.

But the contribution always fails with the error, "Make sure your billing fields are correct."

And they are.

I am using the IATS payment processor. The docs said that as long as the payment processing happens from your web site and not on a third party site (like PayPal standard), then payments should work.

NOTE: the contact-type that is making the contribution is an organization, not an individual.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple commits which were added after the 4.9 release which you might want to try patching: [d41197d](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform_civicrm.git/commit/d41197d) and [2f556df](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform_civicrm.git/commit/2f556df)

Comment: Hi Coleman, I applied those two patches. Now upon submit, the response is "A fatal error was triggered: is not of type String." Any ideas?

Comment: That's progress :)
Can you provide details/backtrace from that, and let's take this conversation over to the webform_civicrm issue queue on drupal.org.

Comment: This question has been moved to the webform_civicrm issue queue at drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2381389